# Google Calendar embed code not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, calendar

I've have an embedded Google calendar (iframe) in my website for months now and today it just stopped showing up. It's an intermittent problem, sometimes it shows up just fine, other times is doesn't show up at all and then other times the events show up but the calendar view doesn't show up.

I've debugged it in Firefox and I've gotten the following error:

TypeError: window_.init in not a function

I've tested it with 6 different calendars on different google accounts and they all seem to be performing the same way with the same errors.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Starting to see this behavior all of a sudden as well